# segmentation faults while writing long long

Tags: c++

i am getting segmentation fault when i am writing long long instead of int.. what should i do ? here is a peice of my code

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n,a[n],i,count=0,c=0,c1=0,j;
    cin>>n;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    sort(a,a+n);
    int r=a[n-1]-a[0];

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(abs(a[j]-a[i])==r)
            count++;
        }
    }

    cout<<r<<" "<<count<<endl;
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: `int n,a[n],...` This creates an array of size n when n has yet to get a value. You need the line `int a[n];` _after_ you get a valid value for n. Even then this is a (shitty) extension. Use `std::vector<int>` instead.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;`  Both these lines are not your friend.  In addition `a[n]` is a compiler extension; don't do it because support for it can be removed on that compiler at any time; as well as the fact that other compilers may not support it.

Comment: You should use valgrind to debug your program. I am pretty sure there are many errors (conditionnal jump etc..). And why using C++ like C? as @MikeVine said, you should use std::vector<int> instead of a[n], for example.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
int n,a[n],i,count=0,c=0,c1=0,j;
cin>>n;
```

You are using `n` before initializing it. Reading `n` from the user **after** declaring a n-sized array is pretty useless. You should use a `std::vector<int>` instead. E.g.

```
size_t n;
std::cin >> n;
auto a = std::vector<int>(n);
```